# IP forwarding and masquerading not working

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I have a Ubuntu based VM with one interface `ens4`.

I would like to use it for IP forwarding and masquerading.

The aim is to make sure that if a request is made to `10.238.232.19:443` on the interface `ens4`, it is forwarded to `172.20.0.42:443` from the same interface `ens4`. Both the CIDR ranges are accessible from the VM.

The commands I am using for this are

```
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens4 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.238.232.14 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.0.42:443
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 172.20.0.42 --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 10.238.232.14
```

I have enabled logging by running the below 2 commands

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -j LOG
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -j LOG
```

So when I access `10.238.232.19:443`, I get only connecting in my chrome browser and the only log I see on my VM is

```
Feb 12 00:53:12 <VM> kernel: [10623.966319] IN=ens4 OUT= MAC=42:01:0a:ee:e8:13:42:01:0a:ee:e8:01:08:00 SRC=10.177.75.199 DST=10.238.232.19 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59341 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

What am I missing here ?